# Archive.php Category.php or Taxonomy.php - Which is correct for my situation?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy, genesis

I'm using Genesis framework and I have this page (http://staging.seedcreativeacademy.co.uk/short-courses/) showing the categories of my custom post type short_courses. I have changed the category name to course_type, by creating a new custom taxonomy.

This is how I want it to work so far (styling needs sorting out admittedly!) Im also using CPT UI plugin.

Now, when I click through to a category, is displays each 'Course in a nice masonry block as you will see here: http://staging.seedcreativeacademy.co.uk/course_type/digital-marketing/

However, I dont want this pages to look like this and I've tried adding custom template for the following:

Archive-short_courses.php & taxonomy-short_courses.php

Archive-course_type.php & taxonomy-course_type.php

But it doesnt seem to alter the layout at all...

Once I pass this hurdle I will want to alter the single.php page for these short courses, but I thought I would start with this first.

Im not sure if genesis blocks this and sets a site wide default? I know if sets a site wide default for the archive settings but I cant find anything about a template, plus i dont know if I shoujld be searching for tutorials on archive.php pages, category.php pager or taxonomy.php pages...

Can someone help me clarify things please?

Comment: can you please add php code you have in taxonomy-course_type.php

Comment: I see it is your child theme which is adding the style. You can see the body class has : masonary in it, then in styles it has styling for that.. you need to get rid of that body class. Let me post answer with the code to alter body classes in genesis

Comment: I currently just have a text div in there to see it it's being picked up... same as I have on the single template which is working... Ill have a look into the plugin issue... Ive disabled some plugins but there is actually a page template called page-masonry.php.. ill look at that

Comment: You need to have  genesis(); as last line in the template also so Genesis class is invoked.

Comment: Ah i understand! As soon as I delete the page-masonry.php things start to work properly! Ill have to find a way to turning it off properly as I might want to keep this layout for the blog!

Comment: Wow good to know! You just need to edit code in your child theme which is applying masonry body class , and limit that to blog only. You may search your child files for word like "body_class" and see if some function you can locate...

Comment: excellent  - thank you :)

Comment: you are welcome! Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 1):

course_type is a term name, not taxonomy name.
So, these are correct for your case:

category-course_type.php (category-{slug}.php is correct format. So check if course_type is correct slug of that category)

single-short_courses.php

Just in case, try reload permalinks via Settings->permalinks->save after making these changes.

Comment: I think OP has custom taxonomy called: course_type , so this answer does not look valid. @ShaunTaylor please update your question again if still not resolved, and yes you can refer to it as Custom Taxonomy (course_type) , seems like something else is going on as your target tempaltes look fine, just genesis uses hooks so could be that function being included via a hook which you would have to remove_action on your template...

Comment: Custom taxonomy: course_type  .... Custom Term: digital-marketing , for this page: http://staging.seedcreativeacademy.co.uk/course_type/digital-marketing/

Comment: The single is working great, but the category-course_type.php not so... I'm using CPT UI and to change the category for my Custom post type I added a new taxonomy and assigned it t the CPT - so I'm just checking this should definitely be category.php and not taxonomy.php?

Comment: Thank you @Mohsin just saw your replay... Your'e correct - course_type is indeed a custom taxonomy... but I cant get taxonomy-course_type.php to be recognised... Ive updated my question with this bit of info, if thats what you meant...

Comment: category is a taxonomy. so taxonomy is correct if you use it instead of category.  i don't know what the course_type is in your website - default category (it is  a term in this case) or custom taxonomy name. If it custom taxonomy then taxonomy-course_type.php and taxonomy-course_type-digital-marketing.php are OK.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your theme or some plugin is adding masnory class to body tag, which then is styled by your child theme. You need to filter that class out of your body tag and then might styling goes to non-masonary styling.

Add following code to your taxonomy-course_type.php file, and also make sure you have genesis(); call as the last thing in the template.

```
add_filter('body_class', 'remove_body_class', 20, 2);

function remove_body_class($wp_classes)
    {
        foreach($wp_classes as $key => $value)
            {
                if ($value == 'masonry') unset($wp_classes[$key]);
            }

        return $wp_classes;
    }
```

Above could should be in custom taxonomy template, which also have genesis(); as last line.

Comment: Sorry - so do you mean I shoujld be using a taxonomy-course_type.php instead of category-course_type.php?

Comment: Ignore that question :) - This code doesn't seem to remove the masonry body class however...